# Inserting a fixed width file in to Hive using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have sample file record like this

```
2018-01-1509.05.540000000000001000000751111EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL
```

and the above record is from a fixed length file and I wanted to split based on the lengths
and when I split I am getting a list as shown below.

```
ListBuffer(2018-01-15, 09.05.54, 00000000000010000007, 5, 1111, EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL)
```

Everything looks fine until now . But I am not sure why is there extra-space adding in each field in the list(not for the first field).

```
Example : My data is "09.05.54",But I am getting as" 09.05.54" in the list.
```

My Logic for splitting is shown below

```
val lengths = List("10", "8", "20", "1", "4","15")

// Logic to Split the Line based on the lengths
  def splitLineBasedOnLengths(line: String, lengths: List[String]): ListBuffer[Any] = {
    var splittedLine = line
    var split = new ListBuffer[Any]()
    for (i <- lengths) yield {
      var c = i.toInt
      var fi = splittedLine.take(c)
      split += fi
      splittedLine = splittedLine.drop(c)
    }
    split
  }
```

The above code take's the line and list[String] which are nothing but lengths as input and gives the listbuffer[Any] which has the lines split according to the length.

```
When we insert into hive because of this issue every column except the first is getting increased by one character

when I use length(COLUMN NAME) it is showing one character extra ie space for every column
```

Can any one help me why am I getting extra space before each field after splitting ?

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't give me spaces and uses a little more idiomatic Scala:

```
def splitThis(line: String, lengths: List[String]): List[String] = {
  def loop(l: String, ls: List[Int], acc: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = 
    if (l.isEmpty || ls.isEmpty) acc else loop(l.drop(ls.head), ls.tail, acc :+ 
l.take(ls.head))
  loop(line, lengths.map(_.toInt), Seq.empty).toList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your data try below.

Here in you data there is extra space between ",".

```
  ListBuffer(2018-01-15,09.05.54,00000000000010000007,5,1111,EMAIL@AAA.BB.CL)
```